# git push does not push latest commit to remote

Tags: git, git-push

git push does not push latest commit to remote.

#### Steps to reproduce:

1. With a local project, last commit amended a few times before push.
2. Create a new empty project. (in gitlab)
3. Add the new project origin.
4. git push -u [origin] [branch].

#### Problem:

git keeps push *outdated* commit to remote!
Not the commits I locally amended before push.

How can I force git to cleanup and don't remember the stale commits?

Added Information: git 2.1.0

Comment: What git branch returns? Are you in a detached head mode? (http://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309)

Comment: I tried to "git remote rm" all other remotes. I don't know if no remote is detached head state. As for the push target, it is a newly created project and a newly added origin, so it should not have a valid HEAD yet.

Comment: I meant: what does the command `git branch` return? In your local repo. Nothing to do with any remote for now.

Comment: You can't delete a commit once it is pushed. You should probably create a new project in Gitlab and push to it

Comment: yes. git branch shows detached state(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `git branch` shows detached state

That would explain why pushing a branch to any remote would push an "outdated" commit: the branch still refer to the old commit, while the new amended commit (referenced by HEAD) is detached from any branch.

You can force a branch to reset to the current HEAD

```
git branch -f master HEAD
```

That would reset the branch master to the current amended commit.

Then you can create a new Gitlab repo, and `git push -u origin master`.

Comment: So the last param in git push, if not A:B, means local refs? I thought it is sort of remote refs.

Comment: @user2771324 in your case, it is the local `master` branch. In general, the last parameter is a **refspec**:  The format of a `<refspec>` parameter is an optional plus `+`, followed by the source object `<src>`, followed by a colon `:`, followed by the destination ref `<dst>`. The `<src>` is often the name of the branch you would want to push, but it can be any arbitrary "SHA-1 expression", such as `master~4` or `HEAD`.